# Proving a function is monotonic decreasing

Tags: calculus, monotone-functions

I need to prove that following function is monotonic decreasing for all $x > 1$ - 
$$F(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2^{x\sqrt{x}}}$$

So by getting the derivate is one way but in this case its a little bit more complicated - is there a simple way to recognize faster when a function is monotonic?

Comment: Not sure it's that simpler, but showing that $\log F$ is decreasing may be easier?

Comment: Write $ \ u \ = \ \sqrt{x} \ $ ($ \ u \ $ is positive), making the function $ \ \frac{u}{2^{u^3}} \ $ : the denominator is pretty definitely growing faster than the numerator...

Comment: Added you an analytic answer down below. Make sure you check it out and ask anything you may not understand. If the answer fits you, make sure you approve it (and any answer by anyone in the future that fits you) so that the thread goes down as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sqrt{x} = u. $ Then you get that $F(u) = \frac{u}{2^{u^3}}$.

$F'(u) = 2^{-u^3}(1 - u^3\log(8))$. For all $u>1 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x} > 1 \Leftrightarrow x>1$, your function is decreasing monotonically.

Comment: Thanks i got the logic , can u just write how you derivate $F(u)$ cause my calculation is different.

Comment: Make sure you vote up to !! I calculate $F(u)$ by using the rule for the derivative of a fraction. Other than that, the derivative of $2^(u^3)$ that you use when you derivate the fraction is $log(2)*2^{u^3}*3u^2$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive+u%2F2%5E(u%5E3)&t=crmtb01 You are missing an $1/2^{u^3}$ factor in the derivative.

Comment: @ClementC. Ye thanks, forgot to write it before the parenthesis.Edited it now